# Remove comma following apply statement and function in R

Tags: r, function, r-markdown, knitr, sapply

When I use the apply statement to run the function it outputs tables with a comma separating each one. I've tried multiple things to see if I can get the commas to stop appearing and keep failing.

Rewrote code to provide example for you...

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set( echo = FALSE , warning = FALSE , message = FALSE , cache = FALSE )

# Load libraries 
library( data.table )
library( kableExtra )
library( knitr )
library( ggplot2 )

```

```{r stackexample}
# Recreate comma issue after sapply 

cols <- list( diamonds )
dfs <- list( diamonds )
jan <- data.table( diamonds ) 
cols_jan <- colnames( diamonds[ , c( 1:4 , 7 ) ])

tabs <- function( number , design , dts ){
          
          x <- y <- z <- NULL 
          dts <- jan
          vars <- cols_jan[number]
          
          out <- x <- y <- z <- NULL 
          x <- dts[ , .( counts = .N ) , by= vars ]
          x <- x[ order( x[ , 1 ] ) ,  ]
          x[ , `:=` ( Percent = ifelse( counts < 30 , NA , counts/nrow( dts ))) , ]
          row.names( x ) <- NULL 
          x[ , counts := ifelse( counts < 30 , NA , as.numeric( counts )) , ]
                
          z <- x 
          z[ , `:=` (
                  counts = scales::number( counts , accuracy = 1 , big.mark="," ) ,
                  Percent = scales::percent( Percent , accuracy = 0.1 ) 
          )]  
                   
          colnames( z ) <- c( ' ' , 'Counts' , 'Frequency' )
          out <- knitr::kable( z , format = 'latex', booktabs = TRUE )
          out
          
          }

```

`r sapply( 2:4 , tabs )`
````

Needs to stay in R, using markdown, outputting in either PDF or Word. I used apply statements but willing to use whatever works.

Seems painfully simple and I feel silly asking. Appreciate any help - also identify that this function can be recreated using far less code...I'm not asking for that, just how to get rid of the commas in between each run (or, in this case, number).

**Thanks much**

[image]

Comment: So your question is:  how to write as  "45678" and not "45,678" , right?  I rather suspect that  `?knitr::kable`  will provide you with info on additional function arguments to define all sorts of display parameters.    Yep:  see `format.args`

Comment: No - I'm asking how to get rid of the comma in between the tables (see image) - there's a comma separating each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally your inline R code should return a scalar (an object of length 1). In your case, `sapply(2:4, ...)` will return an object of length 3. By default, **knitr** will concatenate all elements separated by commas. If that is not desired, you can concatenate them by yourself to make a scalar, e.g.,

```
`r paste(sapply(2:4, tabs), collapse = '\n\n')`
```

Comment: thank you so much! I replaced '\n\n' with '\b' and it worked perfectly. much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow separate printing works like this:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set( echo = FALSE , warning = FALSE , message = FALSE , cache = FALSE )

# Load libraries 
library( data.table )
library( kableExtra )
library( knitr )
library( ggplot2 )

```

```{r stackexample}
# Recreate comma issue after sapply 

cols <- list( diamonds )
dfs <- list( diamonds )
jan <- data.table( diamonds ) 
cols_jan <- colnames( diamonds[ , c( 1:4 , 7 ) ])

tabs <- function( number , design , dts ){
          
          x <- y <- z <- NULL 
          dts <- jan
          vars <- cols_jan[number]
          
          out <- x <- y <- z <- NULL 
          x <- dts[ , .( counts = .N ) , by= vars ]
          x <- x[ order( x[ , 1 ] ) ,  ]
          x[ , `:=` ( Percent = ifelse( counts < 30 , NA , counts/nrow( dts ))) , ]
          row.names( x ) <- NULL 
          x[ , counts := ifelse( counts < 30 , NA , as.numeric( counts )) , ]
                
          z <- x 
          z[ , `:=` (
                  counts = scales::number( counts , accuracy = 1 , big.mark="," ) ,
                  Percent = scales::percent( Percent , accuracy = 0.1 ) 
          )]  
                   
          colnames( z ) <- c( ' ' , 'Counts' , 'Frequency' )
          out <- knitr::kable( z , format = 'latex', booktabs = TRUE )
          out
          
          }

```

`r tabs(2)`
`r tabs(3)`
`r tabs(4)`
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yeah - I was hoping I didn't have to do that because I have 180 tables to run. It's very weird that the comma appears, right?

Comment: Well, at least this provides a sort-of clue as to the source of the problem.  Might be time to notify the author of `knitr` to see what they think.

Comment: @Kendal  It's not difficult:  just write a for-loop  `for(j in 1:180) {r tabs(j)}`   . Meanwhile, someone should check to see **exactly** what `sapply` is feeding to your `tabs` function.

Comment: @Kendal   are you running this from a command line?  what is `r` ?

Comment: could you store everything above the final triple backtick in a text file, then write a separate R script that [1] readLines() in that code chunk [2] programmatically adds each of the tabs(2) , tabs(3) lines to the end of the character vector [3] writeLines the new script to a temporary Rmd and [4] executes the temporary Rmd?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Running in markdown

Comment: @AnthonyDamico definitely doable - thanks for the idea!